# How to create Maps.Me .mwm file extension?

Tags: android, file, maps, offlineapps

I want to know what is .mwm file extension, how can create this file type for using in Maps.Me android application?

I want to use Maps. Me API and create map application that will work offline, I saw in storage that application download maps to directory as .mwm file, and this file little, compact file that whole map comes from this file. I want create this file type but dont know the structure of this file. How can I reach this? Thank you for patience. All suggests are acceptable

Answer (score 0):

.mwm file is nothing but the downloaded map file of an particular area from the maps.me also you can get the map using this link http://direct.mapswithme.com/direct/latest/

Comment: link is broken. (403 Forbidden)